# Tippy.js cannot get tooltip to programatically show using .show() function

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, popover

I've recently been trying to implement tooltips to display errors in long documents that contains a scroll bar. I had originally started with using bootstrap tooltips but ran into some limitations with z-index described here: [Unable to get Bootstrap Tooltip to display above div when inside scroll pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423564/unable-to-get-bootstrap-tooltip-to-display-above-div-when-inside-scroll-pane)

I've since tried switching over to [tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) hoping to have better luck. I have not however been able to get the tooltips to show up programatically using the exact same example as the documentation:

```
const tip = tippy('#myButton')
const el = document.querySelector('#myButton')
const popper = tip.getPopperElement(el)
tip.show(popper)
```

Basically it still has the normal hover behavior. I've created a jsfiddle example of almost exactly how my current page is laidout and hoping to trigger the tooltip to show on page load, not on hover!

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L3jv4a9w/1/

Comment: is the below what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the element selector you were using.

If you update your code to the following it works

```
const tip = tippy('.root2');
const el = document.querySelector('.root2')
const popper = tip.getPopperElement(el);
tip.show(popper);
```

See [js fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/L3jv4a9w/2/) or example in action below.

```js
const tip = tippy('.root2');
const el = document.querySelector('.root2')
const popper = tip.getPopperElement(el)
tip.show(popper)
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@1.2.0/dist/tippy.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@1.2.0/dist/tippy.js"></script>


<div class="root2" title="This is a tooltip"> <b>Tooltip</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Oops that was an oversight on my part. I had copied my code over from my app. You only used 5 random elements before/after the tooltip. Notice how when you do 20+ random text elements and the tooltip is not shown in the current scroll pane it dispalys at the bottom of the screen. This was a limitation I saw with the bootstrap tooltip and I believe it had to do with absolute vs relative positioning

Comment: I will give you the points for this because this solved my original issue. But perhaps ask my follow up question on their github as this may be a limitation of the library